# Listener Log Oracle 11g R2

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, logs, listener

I'm using Oracle 11gR2 in RHEL5. Now a days my application, during run time, is showing exception as below.

```
  Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

and

```
 Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

It happens only during the peak time.

Where can I find the reason? Somewhere it might be logging all. Where is it? I checked the `alert_db.log` as well as `log.xml` inside the tnslsnr, but couldn't find anything relating this.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/trouble.htm#NETAG433) explains how to go about configuring listener tracing, but in summary:

Add:

```
TRACE_FILE_<LISTENERNAME>=listener.log
TRACE_DIRECTORY_<LISTERNAME>=/path_to_your_log_directory
TRACE_LEVEL_<LISTENERNAME>=user
```

You can up the `TRACE_LEVEL` to `admin` or `support` if you need more information, but be aware that they generate increasing amounts of output.

Your issue could be due to either a DB not being able to service a request due to the maximum number of processes being reached (check the alert log), a lack of resources on the box (are kernel parameters set correctly?) or an outright DB crash.

Comment: In the alert log I didn't found anything relating to this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the database running? Execute:

`ps -ef | grep pmon`.

You can re-register the database with the listener by executing the statement:

`ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER`

If you execute it, you should is a log message in listener.log immediately.
But under normal circumstances the database does this by it's own periodically. You can also check database parameters `listener`, `local_listener`, ...
Or you can use old style way, you can "hardcode" the database's `SID` directly in `listener.ora`.

PS: what the the load of the system?